# Induction Proof of Loop Invariance Given the Invariance

Tags: solution-verification, induction, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms, invariance

Consider the following program segment

```
i=1
total = 1

while i<n
  i = i + 1
  total = total + i
```

Let *p* be the proposition "total = $\frac{{i}{(i+1)}}{2}$ " and $ i ≤ n $
Use mathematical induction to prove the that *p* is a loop invariant.

Having issues simplifying and solving the problem.

1. I claim that the loop invariant is **$t=\frac{{i}{(i+1)}}{2}$**
2. I start off with the Base Case of *i=1 and t=1* which proves to be true
   $$1 = \frac{{1}{(1+1)}}{2}$$
3. Now I let t<sub>B</sub> and i<sub>B</sub> be the values at the end of the x<sup>th</sup> iteration of the loop and t<sub>A</sub> and i<sub>A</sub> be the vales **after** (x+1)<sup>th</sup> iteration of the loop
4. So my Induction Hypothesis is that my loop invariant holds at the end of the x<sup>th</sup> iteration

$$IH: t_b = \frac{{i_b}{(i_b+1)}}{2}$$

Whereas

t<sub>A</sub> = t<sub>B</sub> + i<sub>B</sub>

i<sub>A</sub> = i<sub>B</sub> + 1

And my guard condition is i<sub>b</sub> ≤ n

So then we would have

$$ t_a = t_b+i_a $$
$$ = \frac {{i_b}{(i_b+1)}}{2} + ia $$
$$ = \frac {{i_b}{(i_a)}}{2} + \frac{2i_a}{2}$$
$$ = \frac {{i_b}{(i_a)}+{2i_a}}{2}$$
$$ = \frac {{i_a}{(i_b}{}+{i_a)}}{2}$$

And now I'm stuck. I'm having trouble understanding where to use the updated variables in the Induction proofs as one of the variables relies on its previous iteration. Thank you for your time everyone.

<sub>Update I've figured out subscripts</sub>

Comment: I think you need to do something like let: $$ p_n = \frac{n(n + 1)}{2} $$ then: $$ p_{n + 1} = p_n + n + 1 = \frac{n(n + 1)}{2} + n + 1 = \frac{(n + 1)(n + 2)}{2}$$ and so if $p_n$ holds then so does $p_{n + 1}$, i.e. $p_n \implies p_{n + 1}$